# How to define and fill a dict of dicts of lists

Tags: python, dictionary, defaultdict

I have to fill a dictionary of the type:

```
partial[sequence][exp_id] = [item_1, ..., item_n]
```

this can be done in this way:

```
partial = defaultdict(dict)

for sequence in sequences:
   for exp_id in exp_ids:
       for item in data:
           partial[sequence].setdefault(eid, []).append(item)
```

Is there a more effective way?
Something like:

```
partial = defaultdict(defaultdict(list))

for sequence in sequences:
   for exp_id in exp_ids:
       for item in data:
          partial[sequence][exp_id].append(item)
```

would be perfect but unfortunately doesn't work because `defaultdict` wants a callable as first argument

Comment: I would like to understand what you are doing, but you aren’t using partial anywhere after its definition. I want to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: @Profpatsch You are right. I corrected the wrong names. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
partial = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```

Answer (score 6):

try:

```
partial = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))
```